# FFMPEG Adding TEXT to SOUNDWAVE Video from Audio

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am creating an audio to soundwave video with

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=line,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy soundwaves.mp4
```

I want to add text to the top left corner using an overlay but cannot get the syntax right

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=line,format=yuv420p[v]; [bg]overlay=0:H-h,drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontcolor=white:x=10:y=10:text='soundwaves'[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy soundwaves.mp4
```

What is the correct way to add text to this video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex 
      "[0:a]showwaves=s=1920x1080:mode=line,
            drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontcolor=white:x=10:y=10:text='soundwaves',
            format=yuv420p[out]"
      -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy soundwaves.mp4
```

The overlay filter is not required here, since you're not overlaying anything.